# Out-of-bounds "NSRangeException" when scrolling on a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am building a simple directory app that scans an Amazon Dynamo DB database, and presents the data in a tree-like structure. Some of the items in the database only have children, while others contain address and phone number details in addition to children. Detail items do not have their own entry in the database--they just have a field within another item, which reduces the size of the database by a non-trivial amount.

When my UITableView has to display both details and children at the same time, it gets a little tricky. The details are loaded at the top of the screen, and each time a detail is loaded, I increment an _arrayOffset. The _arrayOffset is subtracted from indexPath.row so that the table is correctly populated with the array of children, starting at index [0]. This works perfectly when the list can be displayed without scrolling. However, if I scroll down past the details and back up, I immediately get an NSRangeException. In the particular case that I'm looking at, I have 22 children to display and 1 detail. The error says:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason '***
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 22]'
```

I know that 4294967295 is (2^32) - 1, so what I'm pretty sure is happening is that when my detail reloads at the top of the table, it increments my _arrayOffset again, and then the UITableView tries to use the item at index -1.

How can I avoid this? Is there a way to only increment the _arrayOffset the first time details are loaded? Can I increase the number of cells the UITableView loads at once, and would it slow it down too much if I have to load, say, 50 cells at once? And if my code-less question is not specific enough to answer any of those question, can someone help me understand how the UITableView reuses cells so I can better debug this?

Edit 1:

The index is generated by cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

then

```
if (containsDetails)
{
    // Add the details to cell.detailTextLabel
    self.arrayOffset++
}
```

and then....

```
// If _tableRows isn't empty
if (_tableRows.count)
{
    DDBTableRow *item = self.tableRows[indexPath.row-self.arrayOffset];
    cell.textLabel.text = item.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
 }
```

Edit 2:

I don't believe numberOfRowsInSection is the culprit, but I'll post it anyway.
rowCount has always been correct, even on crashes.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // If we're displaying details, check to see if the item has a phone number, fax, and address.
    // Add one to rowCount for phone number and fax. For address, add two, so we can display a dummy
    // cell at the end. If we don't do this, the size of every cell will be the size of the address
    // cell (big) and that looks messy.

    NSInteger rowCount = 0;

    if (self.showDetails == YES)
    {
        if ([_tableRow.phone length] > 0)
        {
            rowCount++;
        }
        if ([_tableRow.fax length] > 0)
        {
            rowCount++;
        }
        if ([_tableRow.address length] > 0)
        {
            rowCount++;
            rowCount++;
        }
    }

    rowCount += [self.tableRows count];

    return rowCount;
}
```

Comment: Where is your numberOfRowsInSection function?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in at: `DDBTableRow *item = self.tableRows[indexPath.row-self.arrayOffset];` and see what `self.arrayOffset` is before it crashes.

Comment: Right before the crash, self.arrayOffset is 1.

Comment: And indexPath.row is 0, right? So then it's going to index -1 which is impossible.

Comment: When the UITableView first loads, indexPath.row of the first non-detail item is 1, so I have to subtract self.arrayOffset. However, when I scroll back up, it crashes on indexPath.row = 0, but I'm not seeing why it would become 0.

Comment: Does the cell at the top of the tableview always have indexPath.row = 0, regardless of whether or not there are hidden cells above it? That would explain some things.

Comment: The first row always has indexPath of 0. It depends on how you're implementing the tableview as to whether or not hidden cells take up rows. @effendo